# ASP.NET crystal report parameters from query string not working

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am updating an existing reporting system in ASP.NET which uses crystal reports. In the past reports  have been given their parameters by session variables, however I now have a need to post them in the web address e.g.

www.mysite.com?reportname=myreport&year=2009

I have grabbed the parameters off using request.querystring as usual and the report generates and the first page looks ok. However as soon as I try to go to the next page on the report viewer toolbar the report errors getting no data.

If I remove the parameters and hard code some values the page works fine. Any ideas if this is a known issue with crystal reports? Is there a way around it?

I'm thinking it's something to do with caching not working when parameters are in the address, have something in the back of my mind about it

Comment: It could be something to do with the postback. Can you post some sample code on how the data is being retrieved from the querystring and then fed to the viewer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with crystal reports, it must use the address in some way. I modified my code to put in an intermediate page where the request.querystring variables are put into the session and then the user is forwarded to another page which generates the report.